# What is special about deleting an empty list?

Tags: python

Consider the following...

```
In [1]: del []

In [2]: del {}
  File "<ipython-input-2-24ce3265f213>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't delete literal

In [3]: del ""
  File "<ipython-input-3-95fcb133aa75>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't delete literal

In [4]: del ["A"]
  File "<ipython-input-5-d41e712d0c77>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't delete literal
```

What is special about `[]`? I would expect this to raise a `SyntaxError` too. Why doesn't it? I've observed this behavior in Python2 and Python3.

Comment: In the same fashion: `[] = ()` works, but `"" = ""` doesn't

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`del` statement syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) allows for a [`target_list`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target_list), and that includes a list or tuple of variable names.

It is intended for deleting several names at once:

```
del [a, b, c]
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
del (a, b, c)
```

or

```
del a, b, c
```

But python does not enforce the list to actually have *any* elements.

The expression

```
del ()
```

on the other hand *is* a syntax error; `()` is seen as a literal empty tuple in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, something interesting to note though is that `del ()` gives us `SyntaxError: can't delete ()` instead of `SyntaxError: can't delete literal`, which might mean it is checked separately. For some reason it does not check that for lists. :)

Comment: But in the docs, neither `target` nor `target_list` can be empty. Seems quite odd the Syntax error for `()` but not for `[]`

Comment: Maybe this is an implementation thing?

Comment: @frb: it's the parser that gives those errors; and I am 90% certain that's because parenthesis also can group expressions together, not just create tuples.

Comment: Probably the docs are wrong: `target` can contain starred expressions, but yet you can't do `del a, *b`. Also `target_list` must contain at least one `target` and `[]` is not a valid target just the way `()` isn't also

Comment: @JBernardo: I'd say: file a bug report in the [python tracker](http://bugs.python.org/) and let the devs sort it out. :-) I think `del []` should raise a `SyntaxError` too; it serves no discernable purpose.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the implementation of `del` is already very odd... `del a, b, (c, d), (e, (f, (g,), h)), [i], []` Check the disassembled bytecode and tell me if the parentheses makes sense. The docs problem is the smallest error here

Comment: @JBernardo: what py version? In 3.3 the bytecode looks fine to me; am I missing something? `target_list` syntax is primarily meant for assignment; it's been reused for `del` making parsing easier and simpler. That that means you can create nonsensical delete statements, so be it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that's a nonsensical statement. They could have used the `global` or `nonlocal` syntax that is just a bunch of comma-separated names... BTW, this causes a [bug in Pypy](https://bugs.pypy.org/issue1364)